# Big-Oh substraction disproving statement

Tags: big-o

Hi I'm struggling with disproving the following statement:

Given:

```
f1(n)=O(g1(n)), f2(n)=O(g2(n)), for all n: f1(n) >= f2(n)
```

Statement:

```
f1(n) - f2(n) = O(min{g1(n),g2(n)})
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: What have you found so far?

Comment: f2(n)<=f1(n)<=c*g1(n)

Answer (score 0):

You have to find a counter example: here is one:

```
f1(n) = g1(n) = n+1
f2(n) = g2(n) = 1
```

Clearly the hypothesis is fulfilled. Now

```
f1(n) - f2(n) = n
```

and

```
min{g1(n), g2(n)} = 1
```

but this isn't true that `n` is a `O(1)`.